# Tinymce paste_preprocess unexpected behaviour

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tinymce

In tinymce editor I have the following function while pasting some content.

```
$mceInit['paste_preprocess'] = "function(plugin, o) {
            o.content = '<div class=\"pasted_content\">'+o.content+'</div>';
        }";
```

After adding this, when I paste some content it is working as expected.

```
<div class="pasted_content">whatever content I pasted</div>
```

But the problem is whatever I type in the editor after the paste process is also having the above div appended to it. How to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. If you find some solution, post here.

Comment: This seems to be part of a wider problem. If you manually type `<div class="pasted_content">whatever content I pasted</div>` in the text editor and switch back to the visual editor, everything you type afterwards is also having the div appended to it. Depending on your use case, wordpress shortcodes may be an alternative. Instead of pasting the div you could paste a shortcode. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API